# Does my Python code have any security issues with the new implemented approach?

Tags: python, code-injection

I am currently responsible for implementing new functions, which are supposed to be secure. As we had recently code injections, I implemented an if block to black list all dangerous commands.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
def main():
    print("What command you want to do?")
    text = input('>>> ')
    for keyword in ['eval', 'exec', 'import', 'open', 'os', 'read', 'system', 'write']:
        if keyword in text:
            print("You are not allowed to do this")
            return;
    else:
        exec(text)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

A good friend told me to not use a blacklisting approach, but since I can't imagine how to break through this, I am asking here. The `exec` function is executed with sudo rights on a Ubuntu system, but since the dangerous commands like `import` or `os` are blocked, this should be pretty secure now. If not, please show me an example how to break it. As we have limited resources in our company, I don't want to make things too complicated if not necessary. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @MZ - Im not sure if this is suitable on codereview

Comment: Try inputting - `"lave"[::-1] + "(foo)"`

Comment: Just saying it is not secure doesn't help me. I need a good reason to change my approach. Otherwise it would be lots of effort to write new code. Thank you

Comment: also works: `exec("EVAL".lower() + "(foo)")`

Comment: Thank you @Sayse. Your code example doesn't do anything

Comment: Exactly, you would expect it to say you are not allowed but instead you're able to use eval by  simply inputting it in reverse

Comment: why you guys keep writing comments? just write an answer. thank you

Comment: `exec("imporT oS; oS.sYstem('ls')".lower())`

Comment: generally speaking, whitelisting is easier than blacklisting

Comment: Oh wow that's genius. Didn't think of that. Thank you @Sayse

Comment: @MZ Thank you. you can write this as answer so I can close the question and give you credits

Comment: But how does your first exec gets executed? I blocked that one @MZ

Comment: @derUeberBoss ignore the `exec()` part, the input string is what would be typed. because its all caps and your blacklist is all lowercase, EVAL will pass

Comment: Thaank you. It passed bu didn't executed the ls @MZ

Comment: I put "imporT oS; oS.sYstem('ls')".lower(). It passed my blacklisting, but did not executed the ls command @MZ

Comment: just tested again. it does not bypass my blacklisting.the reversing of the shell commands get caught as well. @Sayse

Comment: `__builtins__.__dict__['Exec'.lower()]("from subprocess i"+"mport call;call('echo Evil code here'.split())")`  You will pretty much never win with a blacklisting approach, if you don't trust the user to not try and bypass your filter, you must not run their code.

Comment: that did worked. thank you @AnonCoward. and I am stupid, need to use a whitelisting approach. can you write this as answer so I can close the question ? how did you come up with that huge one ?

Comment: As for how I found it:  Experience.

Comment: A) as others have said, this really is more like a request for a code review, thus off topic here. B) absolutely forget about getting EVAL of user input strings to be safe. If you need security, the real solution would be to step back and look for a solution that doesnt expose something like PYTHON to strings coming from users.

Comment: Which OS, and which account/rights do you use ?

Answer (score 1):

well... I know it's kind of not a complete answer but...

Do you really need to let people run code?

the reason I ask is because it's quite simple to pass an import statement even though it's blacklisted.

try running this:

```
x = "im"; y="port"; print(str(x+y+" module"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The blacklist approach is inherently flawed.  By it's nature, Python has a surprisingly large surface area, and you will forever be at the mercy of having to vet every possible built-in command, along with each and every side effect of the built-ins.  Not to mention, I assume the real script you're using will bring in some library, itself a protentional security concern.

For instance:

```
__builtins__.__dict__['Exec'.lower()]("from subprocess i"+"mport call;call('echo Evil code here'.split())")
```

This bypasses your checks, and lets the user call `exec` and `import`.  This is *not* the only way to bypass your checks.  There are others.

There isn't really a way to vet code to verify its safe automatically.  I'd be hard pressed to imagine a scenario like this where I let users run code at all in an elevated environment.